# meaning of "is by no means given"

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

1. What does "though the latter is by no means given" mean?
2. Does the "latter" refer to "renewal"?

> Not only do many of these incursions into the cityscape possess a
>   ‘temporary aspect’ in their realisation but frequently they seek out
>   temporary spaces as their settings: liminal sites in a state of
>   transition from physical decline to renewal – though the latter is by
>   no means given – or whose complex sociocultural make-up renders them
>   subject to continual fluctuations.

Answer (score 1):

Given means **something granted: something assumed as actual or hypothetical**.

The latter does refer to renewal and the renewal here is not a given thing. It talks of sites that are being considered as settings, temporarily, for the building projects planned to take place. These sites are considered to be under transition, liminal because it is still under way or barely existing, from a state of **physical decline to renewal**. But by no means is the renewal of these sites a granted or a sure thing(given thing) and that is the reason for mentioning "though the latter is by no means given.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm getting heartburn from trying to digest that run-on sentence,
   but, yes, I believe that "the latter" refers to "renewal".
2. Would you understand it if it said "though the latter is given"
   or "the latter of which is given"? 
   The term "given", in this context, means that, in the universe of claims and speculations, this thing is *given* to you as **the Truth**. 
   It is guaranteed or assured.

   > [***given***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/given): stated, fixed, or specified;
   >   known or independently determined; an established fact, condition, factor, etc.

   "given" in this context would mean that the sites that are
   "in a state of transition" are certain to reach a state of "renewal" eventually.
3. [***by no means***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/by--no--means) simply means "not"
   (although it is a bit more emphatic).